# scipy skewnorm mean not matching theory?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using **scipy skewnorm** to create a skewed distribution with a loc and scale.

I adjust the loc and scale passed to scipy.stats.skewnorm based on Adelchi Azzalini's page([Here is link](http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/Intro/intro.html)), using the section at the bottom of that page on "mean value" and "delta".

The code I'm using is:

```
import math
import scipy.stats

skew = -2
mean = 0.05
stdev = 0.05

delta = skew / math.sqrt(1. + math.pow(skew, 2.))
adjMean = mean - stdev * math.sqrt(2. / math.pi) * delta
adjStdev = math.sqrt(math.pow(stdev, 2.) / (1. - 2. * math.pow(delta, 2.) / math.pi))

print 'target mean={:.4f} actual mean={:.4f}'.format(mean, float(scipy.stats.skewnorm.stats(skew, loc=adjMean, scale=adjStdev, moments='mvsk')[0]))
print 'target stdev={:.4f} actual stdev={:.4f}'.format(stdev, math.sqrt(float(scipy.stats.skewnorm.stats(skew, loc=adjMean, scale=adjStdev, moments='mvsk')[1])))
```

When I run it, though, I'm not getting the mean I expect, while the stdev is what I expect:

```
target mean=0.0500 actual mean=0.0347
target stdev=0.0500 actual stdev=0.0500
```

I feel like I'm missing something either about skewnorm or in scipy.stats.skewnorm...

I have numerically integrated the distribution and the mean matches the "actual mean" above.

Comment: Can you add sufficient code to your example so we can just copy and run it without having to add more definitions and imports?  Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more advice about creating a good question.

Comment: Sorry about that...fixed. Thought I'd pasted in all the code but missed the top lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an algebra mistake. You have

```
adjMean = mean - stdev * math.sqrt(2. / math.pi) * delta
```

but on the right side, `stdev` should be `adjStdev`.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
import math
import scipy.stats

skew = 2.0
mean = 1.5
stdev = 3.0

delta = skew / math.sqrt(1. + math.pow(skew, 2.))
adjStdev = math.sqrt(math.pow(stdev, 2.) / (1. - 2. * math.pow(delta, 2.) / math.pi))
adjMean = mean - adjStdev * math.sqrt(2. / math.pi) * delta

print('target mean={:.4f} actual mean={:.4f}'.format(mean, float(scipy.stats.skewnorm.stats(skew, loc=adjMean, scale=adjStdev, moments='mvsk')[0])))
print('target stdev={:.4f} actual stdev={:.4f}'.format(stdev, math.sqrt(float(scipy.stats.skewnorm.stats(skew, loc=adjMean, scale=adjStdev, moments='mvsk')[1]))))
```

Here's the output:

```
target mean=1.5000 actual mean=1.5000
target stdev=3.0000 actual stdev=3.0000
```

Comment: Thanks! What I get for not actually writing down the equations.